# Hovering over an image in one div container to have an img or background appear in or over top of a different container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

So I'm fairly new as far as coding goes, just so everyone knows.
I'm trying to accomplish two simultaneous things

1. The first is, I would like be able to hover over an image in one container and have another image in a different container appear. Even if that means having an image that technically overlaps the container and just happens to have the same dimensions (which are width: 350px and height: 205px, by the way). If another solution is to have the initial image be a clickable link to open the second image, that would be fine too. In fact, that'd be preferable.

2. I need to do this multiple times, each with different initial and secondary images, with float:right or a similar css function involving setting the sets of initial images being wrapped to the right of my first div container.

3. I need to maintain the set of initial images (buttons), in two rows, with overlap-y: hidden and overlap-x: scroll.

My css for the button images is this, and must either stay this way or have a similar effect:

```
    div.img {
         margin: 10px;
         **padding: 5px;**
         **height: 38px;**
         **width: 38px;**
         float: right;
         display:inline;}   

             div.img img {
                  **height: 38px**
                  **width: 38px**
                  display: inline;
                  float:right;
                  margin: 10px;
                  **border: 12px solid #ffffff;**
                  **border-radius: 8px;**
                  **box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #888888;**
```

I put all the key points of the css that I need to keep (or display in a similar fashion) in bold. The part in question is the display: inline function. I need my set of images to be in two rows, wrapping to the right side of the container (or at least scrolling horizontally), but instead they are displaying as two rows of three, then one vertical column that is no longer aligned with the two rows of three.

To see the type of solution I'm looking for, here's the page:

http://hellothisismelody.tumblr.com/codeconstruction/

As you can see, it's set up like a Nintendo 3DS. I'm looking to make functioning buttons on the bottom screen that make an image appear in the top screen, and looking to have those images set up like the home screen of a Nintendo 3DS, which looks like this:

[Click for Nintendo 3DS Homescreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5cHi.jpg)

Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, you can use this:

```
<div class=container1>
    <img src='blah1.png'>
</div>

<div class=container2>
    <img src='blah2.png'>
</div>

$('.container1 img').hover(function() {
    $('.container2 img').get(0).src = 'blah3.png';
});
```

Comment: Alright, cool. Am I able to us this multiple times? Could I potentially create multiple containers to achieve the effect I'm looking for in my second question?

Comment: What do you mean by do it multiple times? Will there only ever be 2 images displayed at 1 time to the user? Or will there be like 2 columns of images?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant like, am I able to use that script for several pairs of "container 1" images and "container 2" images? Or am I limited to only being able to use that script once to work with one pair. (Sorry if that doesn't make sense. I'm new.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the current code is limited to 1 pair of containers. For jQuery code to work with multiple containers/images it kind of depends on what the html code looks like when using multiple containers/images.